# What is the problem with this simple SQL expression?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select * from TABLE
where (BIT_COLUMN_1 = 1) <> (BIT_COLUMN_2 = 1)

select * from TABLE
where (BIT_COLUMN_1 = 1) = (BIT_COLUMN_2 = 1)
```

Both expressions result in error Incorrect syntax near '<' or '='.

In the case of the above example the where clause can be rewritten as:

```
select * from TABLE
where BIT_COLUMN_1 = BIT_COLUMN_2
```

...which works fine. However the case I'm actually trying to resolve is this:

```
select * from TABLE
where (BIT_COLUMN_1 = 1) <> (NULLABLE_COLUMN_2 is null)
```

...which I haven't been able to get to work at all.

I'm using SQL Server Express 2016.

Comment: You are trying to use boolean logic which doesn't exist in t-sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL doesn't support boolean values as a type.  It can evaluate logical conditions as a predicate, like:

```
where BIT_COLUMN_1 = 1
```

But it can't evaluate a logical condition as a boolean value, and then compare it to something else, like:

```
where (BIT_COLUMN_1 = 1) = TRUE
```

You need to do a little boolean algebra of your own to make valid SQL.  In pseudocode: If A and B are valid predicate clauses, and you want rows where either both are true or both are false, you would write

```
where (A AND B) OR (NOT A AND NOT B)
```

Depending on the conditions, you may need to include special considerations for NULLs as well.

Answer (score 2):

AS Sean commented, thank Sean, this will never return a result but it is what you were asking for:

```
select * from table
where BIT_COLUMN_1  <> NULLABLE_COLUMN_2
and BIT_COLUMN_1  = 1
and NULLABLE_COLUMN_2  is null;
```

You can also use this maybe:

```
select * from table
where BIT_COLUMN_1  = 1
and NULLABLE_COLUMN_2  is null;
```

depending on your needs of course...
Or maybe simply use or operator:

```
select * from table
where BIT_COLUMN_1  = 1
or NULLABLE_COLUMN_2  is null;
```

Comment: The first and third predicates here are somewhat conflicting. If Col2 IS NULL the first predicate can never be true. The result of the first predicate would be NULL. I would remove the first one and this sounds like what they are after.

Comment: I agree with you but the op has the <> specified and I am counting on the fact that the values 1 and null are just for example and are not relevant... Maybe, I do not know... always is better to test on data example right?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way to get that logic:

```
select * from TABLE
where ((BIT_COLUMN_1 = 1) and (NULLABLE_COLUMN_2 is not null)
       or (BIT_COLUMN_1 <> 1) and (NULLABLE_COLUMN_2 is null))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `CASE` expressions:

```
select * from TABLE
where 
  case when (BIT_COLUMN_1 = 1) then 1 else 0 end 
  <> 
  case when (NULLABLE_COLUMN_2 is null) then 1 else 0 end
```